# What does the shape of the radial distribution function(RDF) indicate?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, intermolecular-forces, molecular-interactions

From my understanding, generally in the RDF plot for liquids, the value of $g(r)$ goes to a maximum near the first solvation shell and then goes to a minimum and then slowly tapers off to the value of 1. For solids, we observe a discontinuous RDF plot because the atoms are considered to be fixed in particular positions and there exists empty space where no atom exists.

Now in a system of solution at a supercritical state, I am trying to understand the plot of RDF between the solute and the solvent molecular pairs. This RDF only keeps increasing and tapers off to 1.

**Is this a reasonable RDF plot for the supercritical phase and if so, how should I interpret it?**

Its not clear to me how I could determine the first solvation shell since there is no minima or how to calculate the coordination number in such a case. The density of the molecules in the shells around the solute is always less than the bulk density, so I wonder if this implies repulsion between the solute and the solvent.

Below is the figure for your reference.
[image: Supercritical fluid RDF plot. Steadily increases towards 1 before tapering off around 4 angstroms]

Snapshot of the system:

[image: Simulation cell of supercritical fluid]

Comment: I don't specifically have any expertise on supercritical phases, but it it basically a fluid that behaves like a gas, and has a liquid like density. I would not expect its RDF to be bizarre, as you have shown. see for example https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Zoomed-in-figure-of-the-structural-crossover-of-the-Radial-distribution-functions-RDF_fig4_322650988

Comment: Was your simulation well equilibrated and frequently sampled once equilibrated? Is that really nanometers on the scale? ALso, what is the g(r) for? ligand - solvent? ligand-ligand?

Comment: @Wesley Hey thanks for the reference. Yes, the system is well equilibrated and frequently sampled and yes, it is nm on the scale(this plot is the running average of the original RDF for every 100 points sampled). When I plot the RDF for the solvent-solvent molecular pairs, it is like the RDF of supercritical argon. However, I observe this behaviour with the solute-solute or the solute-solvent pairs.

Comment: I think it makes sense for solute-solute, since they are "dilute" and so would have a lower density in the solution than the bulk. I would not expect this for the solute-solvent though. The job of a solvent is to pack around a solute. If the solvent isn't attracted to the solute, I would expect to see two phases in the simulation box, one for solute the other for "failed" solvent. I think there should be a clear solvation shell with peaks as per normal for solute-solvent. When you visualize it, is there two phases?

Comment: Even if there was phase splitting, I would then expect solute-solute and solvent-solvent to have similar RDF's, and solute-solvent to be the outlier, looking as above perhaps

Comment: +1 but it might be best to reduce it to one question!

Comment: @Wesley Interesting, but I do not find two different phases. I have uploaded the snapshot of the system for which I calculated the RDF between solvent and solute. Is it possible that the distribution of the solvent is very different around different solute molecules, that on averaging it shows no maximum?

Comment: I am at a bit of a loss :) I think we would see "clumps" if this were the case. Even then though, those clumps would help form a peak. Is it possible gromacs is mislabelling the solute group? (I am assuming GROMACS, but insert with actual program)... this seems almost like a labelling or algorithm issue. It is almost like it is failing to normalize it, or, incorrectly normalizing it

Comment: @KavyaMrudula Excluding label mismatching issue in GROMACS, I would recommend three tests. 1) Check the coordination number for the RDF plots wrt to $r$ for both components. You can compare this with results for Argon gas and water 2) If you are dealing with a molecular system, checking partial (element-wise) RDFs would be really helpful as this would resolve any anomalous distribution issues 3) Finally you can look into Spatial Distribution Function (SDF) which gives you an averaged 3D solvation shell around your solute.

Comment: @KavyaMrudula have the comments been helpful? Do you have any update about this question now that it's more than 6 months old? Please update us!

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments.